# Zend + Using names with brackets (array notation) in FormSelect view helper rendered as multiple select element, not a regular dropdown

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

In my project, I am required to have many drop-down fields with array-notated names, like so:

```
<select name="language[]">...</select>
<select name="language[]">...</select>
<select name="language[]">...</select>
```

Since I need to render Zend's `formSelect` view helper for it, I thought it was as simple as doing:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 3; $++){
    echo $this->formSelect('language[]', $this->languages[$i],
                                         $this->attribs[$i],
                                         $this->languageOptions[$i]);
}
```

But I was wrong: Instead of rendering them as regular drop-down fields, Zend decides to be a  smarty-pant and render them as multiple-select fields, instead.

I understand the thinking behind this behavior, but it just so happens that it the help `formSelect` provides is too much for my needs.

Now, I can amend it with using JavaScript to remove the `multiple="multiple"` attribute to transform them to regular drop-downs...

But out of curiosity, is there a way to make `formSelect` render these elements as regular drop-down fields, other than modifying its underlying code?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, the `formSelect` helper is deciding to make it a multi-select based on the fact that the element name is an `array[]`.

You can override the behavior however.

To do so, add `multiple => false` to your list of `$attribs` for the element.

E.g.

```
$attribs = array('multiple' => false, 'class' => 'selection');
echo $this->formSelect('not_array[]', '', $attribs, $options);
```

This should prevent it from trying to make the element support more than one selection.